# C Program that takes pairs of numbers from a file, calculates newton(n,k), and writes answer to another file

Tags: c, factorial

I need a help with a program that takes pairs of numbers from a txt file, calculates the Newton coefficient (**n! / (n! . (n-k)!)**), and writes the answer (score) to the other txt file. For now I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void factorial() {
    long l1, l2;
    long score = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < l2; i++) {
        score = (score * (l1 - i + 1) / i);
    }
}

void read() {
    long l1, l2;
    long score = 1;
    FILE *file = fopen("pairs.txt", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("sum.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(file, "%ld%ld", &l1, &l2) == 2) {
        factorial();
        fprintf(file2, "%ld", score);
    }
    printf("Score is: %ld", score);
    fclose(file);
    fclose(file2);
}

int main() {
    read();
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that when I start the program it shows me answer `Score is: 1`, and there is nothing in the file **sum.txt**.

Comment: `long l1, l2;` at `factorial`. These are not initialized. Even though it is used. You (`read`) pass `l1` and `l2` to `factorial` as arguments. and `factorial` return `long` as `score`.

Comment: You opened `file2` in read-only mode; thus, you can't write to it, AND you didn't check to see if an error occurred, so you blithely continued onwards even when your call to fprintf failed. ALSO - please edit your question and include the contents of your `pairs.txt` file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You must pass arguments to the `binomial` function, return the result with the `return` statement and store the return value in the calling code.
- Your function to compute the Newton binomial coefficients is incorrect.
- You should open the output file **sum.txt** for writing with the `"w"` mode string.
- You should check if `fopen()` succeeded at opening the files. As posted, your code probably fails to open the output file **sum.txt** that does not exist because it tries to open it for reading. Hence `file2` is `NULL` and invoking `fprintf` with a null stream pointer has undefined behavior.  This would explain the crash you observe.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long binomial(long n, long k) {
    long value = 1;
    if (k < n - k) {
        k = n - k;
    }
    for (long i = n; i > k; i--) {
        value *= i;
    }
    for (long i = k; i > 1; i++) {
        value /= i;
    }
    return value;
}

int read(void) {
    long n, k, score;
    FILE *file1, *file2;

    file = fopen("pairs.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening pairs.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    file2 = fopen("sum.txt", "w");
    if (file2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening sum.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fscanf(file, "%ld%ld", &n, &k) == 2) {
        score = binomial(n, k);
        fprintf(file2, "%ld\n", score);
    }
    //printf("Score is: %ld\n", score);
    fclose(file);
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    return read();
}
```

Comment: You should also open `file2` for writing, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you opening a file and printing the results in the terminal using printf, when you want the output to be stored in another file? If you want to put output of a program in a file, Redirection is done using the "<" operator(for stdin).

Also there is a segmentation fault when running your program(your fscanf line).
Can you show us a version of your input file(pairs.txt) ?